# .phtml Changes Not Showing On Frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, phtml

I am having an issue in my Magento installation where changes to .phtml files are not reflected on the frontend. I've verified that I am editing the right .phtml file by enabling the debug options for template hints. I've also cleared all Magento and Browser cache. Is there anything else I can do in addition to this to get frontend changes to show up?

Edit: The location of the file is

```
app/design/frontend/hewa/newdesign/template/catalog/category/sidebar/navigation.phtml
```

The line from the XML that defines this template is

```
<block type="hwcatalog/category_sidebar_navigation" name="catalog.sidebar.nav" after="currency" template="catalog/category/sidebar/navigation.phtml"/>
```

The layout xml file is located at

```
app/design/frontend/hewa/newdesign/layout/hwcatalog.xml
```

Here is the relevant section of the XML.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <remove name="category.products"/>
    <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="hwcatalog/category_sidebar_navigation" name="catalog.sidebar.nav" after="currency" template="catalog/category/sidebar/navigation.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.product.list" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="restricted" template="catalog/restricted.phtml" />
            <block type="hwcatalog/product_list_category" name="product_list">
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Here is the setting from the module's config.xml that points to the layout xml

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <hwcatalog>
                <file>hwcatalog.xml</file>
            </hwcatalog>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <catalog>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Hwareh_Catalog before="Mage_Catalog">Hwareh_Catalog</Hwareh_Catalog>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </catalog>
    </routers>
    <events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before>
            <observers>
                <add_additional_handle_on_product_view_page>
                    <class>Hwareh_Catalog_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addAdditionalHandleOnProductViewPage</method>
                </add_additional_handle_on_product_view_page>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: there's also a new blogtype defined, did you write an extension for this?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, yes this is in a custom extension. The .phtml shows on the frontend, but it's an old version.

Comment: are you sure the layout line actually works? maybe the `<reference name="...">` stuff is not set correctly. Can you post the full path to the Xml node?

Comment: Yes, give me one moment. I am editing the question to include that info.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, I've updated the question to include the info

Comment: hm, weird. do you have the frontend->layout->updates->file node in your module's config.xml file?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, yes I do. it points to the correct file. <file>hwcatalog.xml</file>

Comment: i fear i cant help u; my last shot: you are editing a non-anchor category, so `catalog_category_default` is correct in contrast do `catalog_category_layered`?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I apologize, it is indeed catalog_category_layered. Updating question

Comment: Hmk just wanted to make sure you are not looking at the wrong type for your layout. No idea then sry

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this issue when I first started as well. For me it had nothing to do with any code, but rather the fact that I had Cloudflare enabled on my site. Simply changing my website's mode to Development mode fixed it and I seen changes immediately, rather than it taking days for things to show. If your new file dates aren't updating in your FTP after uploading, your issue is identical to mine. Purging the cache via Cloudflare works as well.

Of course, if you're not using Cloudflare, ignore this.

Comment: We do use Cloudflare in production, but in our test server we use nginx with varnish. This issue is on our test server.